# Why can't I use the same object reference in hibernate over & over again?

Tags: java, hibernate, dao

I do not understand why only one row is deleted by the below code.
The same happens for inserting elements.
Can anyone tell me why can't I use the same route reference over & over again?

```
//Begin transaction
        Long id=1;
        Route route = new Route();
        RouteDAO routeDAO = new RouteDAOImpl();
        route.setRouteId(id);
        routeDAO.delete(route);
        route.setRouteId(++id);
        System.out.println(route.getRouteId());
        routeDAO.delete(route);
        route.setRouteId(++id);
        routeDAO.delete(route);
        route.setRouteId(++id);
        routeDAO.delete(route);
//Commit Transaction
```

Thanks.

Comment: So basically whatever changes you do inside an open transaction on same object only the latest one is being committed to DB.
So for this you need to create new objects for each record deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect that a distinct row/`route` is focused when you change the `id` but it's not.
**Any mutation on a persisted object causes its eligibility to update.**

You always use the same `route` reference, although you're mutating it by changing its id, causing an update each time after commit is made.
In reality, Hibernate makes an optimization after commit, to avoid those useless updates, since you precised a delete.

Those updates concerns the same row, explaining why after commit, just one delete occurs.